# UIPageViewControllerDelegate: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [views count] == 3'

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

App crashes with the error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [views count] == 3'

```
 private func rotateFirstPage() {
        guard let pageViewController = pageViewController else {
            return
        }
        if let firstPage = pageDataSource.pages.first {
            pageViewController.setViewControllers([firstPage], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
                        previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
                        transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

    if firstAutoRotation {
        Timer?.invalidate()
        rotateFirstPage()
    }
    pageControl.currentPage = pageDataSource.presentationIndex(for: pageViewController)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it wrapping setViewControllers method in DispatchQueue.main.async {}